# Rebus Saga fires IAmInitiatedBy multiple times

Tags: sql-server, servicebus, simple-injector, rebus, saga

I'm using the latest version of Rebus (0.99.35) together with SimpleInjector (3.1.2). In my first sample project I’m using SQL Server for transport and Sagas.

The problem is that the Saga method `Handle(StartTheSagaMessage message)`, implementing `IAmInitiatedBy<StartTheSagaMessage>`, is called 5 times and I cannot understand why. Furthermore this method publish itself a message that is never received by the bus.

Here is the code for configuration:

```
var container = new Container();

var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .Where(i => i.FullName.StartsWith("Messages"));

container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IHandleMessages<>), assemblies);

var bus = Configure.With(new SimpleInjectorContainerAdapter(container))
    .Logging(l => l.Trace())
    .Transport(t => t.UseSqlServer(connectionstring, "Messages", "consumer"))
    .Routing(r => r.TypeBased().MapAssemblyOf<Job>("consumer"))
    .Sagas(s => s.StoreInSqlServer(connectionstring, "Sagas", "SagaIndexTable"))
    .Options(o =>
    {
        o.SetNumberOfWorkers(1);
        o.SetMaxParallelism(1);
    })
    .Start();

container.Verify();

bus.Subscribe<Step1FinishedMessage>().Wait();
bus.Subscribe<Step2FinishedMessage>().Wait();

var procId = Guid.NewGuid();
bus.Send(new StartTheSagaMessage() { ProcessId = procId });
```

And the Saga Code:

```
public class MySaga : Saga<MySagaData>,
    IAmInitiatedBy<StartTheSagaMessage>,
    IHandleMessages<Step1FinishedMessage>,
    IHandleMessages<Step2FinishedMessage>
{
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }

    protected override void CorrelateMessages(ICorrelationConfig<MySagaData> config)
    {
        config.Correlate<StartTheSagaMessage>(m => m.ProcessId, s => s.SagaProcessId);
        config.Correlate<Step1FinishedMessage>(m => m.ProcessId, s => s.SagaProcessId);
        config.Correlate<Step2FinishedMessage>(m => m.ProcessId, s => s.SagaProcessId);
    }

    public async Task Handle(StartTheSagaMessage message)
    {
        if (IsNew == false)
            return;

        Trace.TraceInformation("Mysaga - got StartTheSagaMessage: {0}", message.ProcessId);
        //The saga is started - Do some stuff - call webservices (in external handler)
        //When this step is finished the external process replies with a "step1FinishedMessage"
        this.Data.SagaProcessId = message.ProcessId;
        //Fake Step1FinishMessage (should be replied from external handler)
        await Bus.Send(new Step1FinishedMessage() { ProcessId = this.Data.SagaProcessId });
    }

    public async Task Handle(Step1FinishedMessage message)
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Mysaga - got Step1FinishedMessage: {0}", message.ProcessId);
        //Sagabehaviour when the Step1 is finished by the external handler
        this.Data.Step1Finished = true;
        //After dalying 10 seconds - Send a step2finishedmessage
        await Bus.Defer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), new Step2FinishedMessage() { ProcessId = this.Data.SagaProcessId });
    }

    public async Task Handle(Step2FinishedMessage message)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        //return Task.FromResult<void>(() => 
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("Mysaga - got Step2FinishedMessage: {0}", message.ProcessId);
            //Step2 is handled - finished the saga
            this.Data.Step2Finished = true;
            this.MarkAsComplete();
        });
    }
}
```

The full sample is based on the [solution available here](https://github.com/torangel/RebusWorker).

What I’m doing wrong?

Thanks for help.

Comment: *solution available here* uses Autofac?

Comment: Yes it does. Source solution also uses old nuget packages.

Comment: Yes I can see, and updating all the packages produces code that does not compile.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to find a sample with sagas using new packages.

Comment: Where is that `SimpleInjectorContainerAdapter` coming from?

Comment: Is: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rebus.SimpleInjector/0.99.34

Answer (score 1):

I changed the Saga and than it works.

I put:

```
    private IBus _bus;

    public MySaga(IBus bus)
    {
        _bus = bus;
    }
```

In place of:

```
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }
```

And then it works! I can't understand why, bacause debugging Bus was not null inside the method.

Comment: The 5 calls indicate that there must have been an error. You should check out the log to see what was wrong. If you log to the trace output, you should probably configure some kind of trace listener that pipes the logs to a file somewhere - alternatively (and this is what I would recommend), use one of the nice .NET logging libraries available, e.g. the excellent [Serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog)

Comment: Unfortunately the were no message in the log. Thank you for the suggestion about Serilog.